# Imposing independence in multivariate MA process

Tags: arima, stochastic-processes, independence

Consider a 4-dimensional MA(q) process:
$$ z_t = A(L) \epsilon_t$$ where $$A(L) = \sum_{j=0}^q  A_j L^j$$ is a matrix-polynomial in the first $q$ powers of $L$.

What is the best way to impose independence between two elements of $z$ without otherwise restricting the generality of the process for $z$? E.g., suppose we want to impose that the $1st$ dimension of $z$ is stochastically independent from the $2nd$ dimension. One way to impose this would be to impose that $A(L)$ is of the following structure $$ A_j = \begin{bmatrix} x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 0 & 0 \\ x &x & x & x \\ x &x & x & x 
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $x$ denotes unrestricted elements. However, it seems that this imposes more restrictions on $z$ than just independence.

Another way would be to let $z$ load on 6 innovations as follows:
$$ A_j = \begin{bmatrix} x & x & x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x & x & x \\ x &x & x & x & x & x \\ x &x & x & x & x & x. 
\end{bmatrix}$$ As far I can tell, this no longer restricts the generality of $z$ beyond imposing independence between the first two dimension. However, now it seems that our specification of $z$ is a bit overblown and we could more efficiently parametrize it.

My question is: What is the most efficient way to impose independence between two dimensions in a multivariate MA(q) process without otherwise restricting the generality of the process?